# Can node-red increase the icon size

Tags: node-red

I saw that node-red can have a switch with only an Icon to it.
Turn red on OFF and turn green for ON, buttt!

Is there a way to increase the size of the icon? You can increase the size of the space used by the switch but NOT the icon itself.
I have a light-bulb switch with no name, just the icon, but is very very tiny and the switch does not offer that support!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the fa-icons you can scale the icon using the following

```
fa-2x fa-lightbulb-o
```

To scale it 2 times

Comment: Thank you, I will test this!